# Integration of elasticsearch and cassandra

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra

I have successfully installed the plugins. ( river and mapper attachments). I am also able to create  , retrieve and delete indices in ES using REST based API interface.
However when i try to sync data from a column in cassandra to an index in ES , I fail.
It will be great if you can exemplify  with an example (including the request sent).

PS - I tried it from the other resources online but it did not help.
Thanks in advance..

Cheers!!

Comment: How does it fail? What error messages do you see? What are the other resources you tried? How did you configure the thing?

Comment: Also which language and client drivers are you using?  It would help us to see the code you're using to A) query Cassandra and B) post to ES.  I currently do this with the C# Nest ElasticSearch and C# DataStax Cassandra drivers.  But if you're using Java, that won't help you much.

Comment: Hi , 

1.I created the following table in cassandra.
cqlsh:keyspacequeue> select * from keyspacequeue.deliveryqueue;

 queuename | bucketid | scheduledtime | messageid
-----------+----------+---------------+-----------
       pkg |       11 |    7827483432 |      null
      suki |       10 |    7827487917 |      null

Comment: My API request
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/summer/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "cassandra",
    "cassandra" : {
        "cluster_name" : "MyCluster",
        "keyspace" : "keyspacequeue",
        "column_family" : "deliveryqueue",
        "batch_size" : 1000,
        "hosts" : "localhost:9163",
        "username" : "cass2",
        "password" : "cass2"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "prodinfo",
        "type" : "product"
    }
}'
{"_index":"_river","_type":"summer","_id":"_meta","_version":1,"created":true}

Comment: 3. Now when I use the GET API to fetch the data from indeax=prodinfo and type=product i get the following response.

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/prodinfo/product/'
{"error":"ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [product]]","status":400}
 
 
I see that the whole request send has been considered as data and indexed by ES.It did not understand the it was supposed to connect to cassandra and get the data.
Where am I  going wrong.